# Pipe returns blank even though the console prints out correct data

Tags: angular, typescript

On initialisation I retrieve all data from API, so the benefit object gets filled out with data.
After that I call another API to get the image data, and fill out the corresponding object with correct base64 data.
So the DOM is written when I try to run this Pipe. And even though `console.log(base64data);` prints correct data, it does not show up in DOM. It is always `<img _ngcontent-ple-c114="" src="">` in my application.
So I know the first API-calls is correct because the Pipe returns correct base64 string....but it does not set it to src in Benefits.component.html.

Why does it not update the Benefits.component.html?

Benefits.component.html

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 bg-white" *ngFor="let benefit of benefits">
 <div class="img-container">
  <img [src]="benefit.logofile_base64 | returnBase64FromBlob" >
 </div>
</div>
```

Benefits.pipe.ts

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'returnBase64FromBlob'
})
export class ReturnBase64FromBlob implements PipeTransform {
  constructor() { }
  transform(value: any ): string {
    if (!value)
      return "";
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(value);
    reader.onloadend = function () {
      var base64data = reader.result;
      console.log("base64data - crmpipe");
      console.log(base64data);
      return base64data;
    }
    return "";
  }
}
```

Result in DOM:

```
<img _ngcontent-ple-c114="" src="">
```

Edit:
Just to ellobarate. The pipe runs two times, first time the console.log(base64data) returns blank, because value is blank. But second time the console.log returns correct data.

Comment: That `return base64data;` will of course be done later after `transform` returned "". Do not read asynchrone, but normally.

Comment: @JoopEggen - I dont know if I understand. Should I avoid using PipeTransform?

Comment: At that moment you _either_ deliver an **`<img>`** with already read base64 data. _Or else_ when the reading takes too long, deliver an **`<img>`** with an URL to your server that reads the base64 data and delivers the _binary_ (=decoded) image file. The _third_ alternative would be to later fill in the HTML with the `<img>` - unnecessarily convoluted IMHO. _I do not know how to use angular's PipeTransform with a asynchrone event as above. I would have expected a file **writer** connected to the pipe - as input; but I am not really understanding your code!_

Comment: the value I get in to the pipe is a object with application/octet-stream;base64. The data I print with console.log is a string wich will looks like this: `data:application/octet-stream;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOYAAAB4CAYAAADmBo6I....`

Comment: However `transform` ends earlier, a `console.log` before the last `return "";` would show that. Maybe you can replace all with `return reader.readAsArrayBuffer(value);` but I am the opposite of an expert there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you define the `onloadend` function and its callback fires, the pipe is always returning an empty string.

There may be a better way to accomplish this, but the first thing that comes to mind is to return a promise or an observable that fires when the `onloadend` event occurs.

I think something like this would work:

```js
  transform(value: any ): string {
    if (!value)
      return of('');

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(value);
    reader.onloadend = function () {
      return reader.result;
    }
    return fromEvent(reader, 'loadend');
```

Then in template, you must use `async` pipe:

```html
<img [src]="benefit.logofile_base64 | returnBase64FromBlob | async" >
```

Comment: Yes, this is closing in :-)
Now in the DOM I got `src="[object Object]"`.

Comment: Looks like I changed some of the code, I still get `src=""`

Comment: Maybe this error gives a direction: `Type 'Observable<Event>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string>'.
  Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'string'`

Comment: Also it looks like  `if (!value) return of('');` alway returns true, because blob always returns undefined.

Comment: Okey. Corrected some errors on my side and it looks like your solution is correct. Now I am able to get the Event data, only need to figure out how to get the currentTarget.result
Got following error `Property 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.`.  If you have any idea I would have appreciated it :-)

Answer (score 1):

@BizzyBob helped me a lot and I will give him correct answer.

But I had to do some adoptions, and wanted to share them:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'returnBase64FromBlob',
  pure: true,
})
export class ReturnBase64FromBlob implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
  transform(value: Blob): any {
    if (!value)
      return of("");
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(value);
    reader.onloadend = function () {
      return reader.result;
    }
    return fromEvent<ProgressEvent>(reader, 'loadend')
      .pipe(
        map(e => {
          const targetImg = (e.target as FileReader | null);
          if (targetImg?.result) {
            return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(targetImg?.result.toString());
          } else {
            return "";
          }
        }
        )
      );

  }
}
```

Now it is solved.